# How to query with parameters in JdbcTemplate

Tags: sql, jdbctemplate

I execute the query using JdbcTemplate to get the list of searched keywords, but it returns nothing.

Is there any other way I can execute the query with parameters ?

```
public List<Detection> findAll(String key) {
    String sql = " SELECT * "
            + "FROM "
            + "    People p "
            + "        RIGHT JOIN "
            + "    Detection d ON p.people_id = d.people_id "
            + "        LEFT JOIN "
            + "    CustomerType ct ON p.customer_type = ct.id "
            + "        LEFT JOIN "
            + "    groups g ON p.group_id = g.group_id "
            + "        LEFT JOIN "
            + "    camera ca ON ca.camera_id = d.camera_id "
            + "where (liveness_status <> 'FALSE' and liveness_status <> 'false') AND ( d.people_id like '%?%' OR  full_name Like '%?%' )"
            + " AND d.day_first_time >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY "
            + " ORDER BY created_time DESC ";
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Detection.class), key, key);
}
```